# ErrorException Undefined variable $employee

Tags: laravel

Using Database Notification I have stored notification in the notification table.

But now I want to display the notification in the blade template.

I have faced an undefined error.

**Controller**

```
$data=Employee::create([
    'first_name'=>$request->input('first_name'),
    'last_name'=>$request->input('last_name'),
    'username'=>$request->input('username'),
    'email'=>$request->input('email'),
    'password'=>$request->input('password'),
    'confirm_password'=>$request->input('confirm_password'),
]);


$admin=Employee::find(1);

$admin->notify(new NotifyAdmin($data));
```

**NotifyAdmin class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Models\Employee; 


class NotifyAdmin extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, Notifiable;
    private $val;

   
    public function __construct(Employee $employee)
    {
       
        $this->val=$employee;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

   
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'username'=> $this->val->username
        ];
    }
}
```

After doing this, the notification is stored in the notification table.
**Now I want to display this notification**

```html
<div class="media-body">
    @foreach($employee->notifications as $row)
        <p class="noti-details"><span class="noti-title">Admin</span> added new doctor <span class="noti-title">{{$row->data['username']}}</span></p>
        <p class="noti-time"><span class="notification-time">4 mins ago</span></p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't included full controller method code, probably you haven't passed variable to view

Comment: show to us your controller

Comment: I think you guys didn't understand my questions. I have stored notifications in the notifications table. But now I want to display notifications to the notification bar. if I use {@foreach($employee->notifications as $row)} this line it shows error.

Comment: What does the `$employee->notifications` relationship look like? From what I can see the line `$admin->notify(new NotifyAdmin($data));` should be the one causing the problem, as $employee isn't getting passed via `$data` correctly. Are you verifying that `$data=Employee::create([` is creating a record?

Comment: @NMahurin yes it creates a record

Comment: How do you have `$employee->notifications` defined on the Employee model?

Comment: @NMahurin here I am confused about what should I use to display notifications?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to all for your support

Answer (score 0):

**this is my controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\helpers\helper;
use App\Notifications\NotifyAdmin;


class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    
   
    

   

     public function InsertEmployees(Request $request)
        {
          
            $data=Employee::create([
                'first_name'=>$request->input('first_name'),
                'last_name'=>$request->input('last_name'),
                'username'=>$request->input('username'),
                'email'=>$request->input('email'),
                'password'=>$request->input('password'),
                'confirm_password'=>$request->input('confirm_password'),
                'phone'=>$request->input('phone'),
                'nid_number'=>$request->input('nid_number'),
                'status'=>$request->input('status'),
                'roles'=>$request->input('roles'),
                'join_date'=>$request->input('join_date'),
    
            ]);
            
            $admin=Employee::find(1);
            
            $admin->notify(new NotifyAdmin($data));
```